# how create c++ Template?

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently trying to write a template specialization for a function that showes the power of different values.
my code is :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
T myfunc(T x)
{
    return x*x;
}
template<>
string myfunc<string>(string ss)
{
    return (ss+ss); 
}
int main()
{
cout<<myfunc("test")<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with:

> error C2784: 'std::_String_iterator<_Mystr> std::operator
>   +(_String_iterator<_Mystr>::difference_type,std::_String_iterator<_Mystr>)'
>   : could not deduce template argument for
>   'std::_String_iterator<_Mystr>' from 'std::string'

Can you please help me detect where exactly is the problem?

Comment: `"test"` won't be deduced as a `std::string`. It's of type `const char[5]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the function a string, not a char array. Try `myfunc(string("test"))`

To expand a little - the choice of which template / template specialisation to use when a function is called is  called template argument deduction.

You want myfunc to be called, however the type of test is char[5] (null character on the end). Therefore the template argument is 'deduced' to be char[5].

Often, char[] can be cast to string implicitly (this is deprecated i believe) in a call to a fully specialised function (not a template function). This implicit cast is because, as user1274223 pointed out, a std::string has a constructor with signature string(const char *) and this constructor is *not explicit*! That is helpful for when we want to pretend c strings (char*) are easily interchangeable with cplusplus strings (`std::string`), however it can be confusing in these types of situations.

The other work around is `myfunc<string>("test")`, because here the template argument is passed directly, and char[] can be cast *implicitly*.

Comment: +1 for including the string() construction. "test" is interpreted as a const char array, not a string, so this call is necessary.

Comment: thank you for your clear explain but unfortunately it has a same error.

Comment: @user3140486 it owrked for me, try #include <string> in case '+' operator is missing from namespace

Answer (score 1):

A template specialization is unnecessary in this case, you should just overload the function:

```
std::string myfunc(const std::string &ss)
{
    return (ss+ss); 
}
```

This way calling it as `myfunct("test")` will work.

For a all the details why function template specializations are usually not usefu you can have a look at Herb Sutter's article [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: yes, but i think the purpose of "test" is for OP to check arguments are being deduced how he wants

Comment: You should mention that std::string has a constructor for const char * that is not explicit, which is why the string literal would be converted to a string.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said.
in addition, I think you need to

```
#include <string>
```

in which the operator+ for strings and string itself declared
the error you get is your compiler try to match all the other operator+ in  and failed.